# Connection String trouble

Tags: database, connection-string

This isn't so much a *programming* issue, but i'm not sure where else to get this level of expertise.

In any case, the issue i'm having is getting a legacy application to run locally on my machine. it connects to a SQL server using this connection string

```
Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=UN;password=PW;Initial Catalog=DB;Data Source=IP
```

(where of course UN, PW, DB and IP are different, real, values)

I've changed it to this, to connect to a SQL Server Express instance on my local box:

```
Data Source=MY-PC-NAME\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DB;Integrated Security=True
```

The app errors out with a generic *cannot connect* type error, which isn't helpful in the least bit.

Anyone have any advice? I don't have much more information on this blasted program ..

Comment: Are you using this string inside a program?  Is it a language that uses backslash as an escape character?  If so, are you escaping it?

Comment: That's actually a good idea, but I'm fairly certain this legacy app was written in VB6, which I don't think anything needs to be escaped, if I'm not mistaken. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This eventually worked `Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=;password=;Initial Catalog=;Data Source=mypcname\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI`

I have no idea why. I needed to specify the integrated security.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
Provider=SQLNCLI10;Server=Server\SQLExpress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername; Pwd=myPassword;
```

VB6 used OLEDB syntax; your previous syntax was for .NET

Comment: No dice. :( Thanks for the try, though!